# How do I delete events in my iPhone calendar posted by Apple

Tags: iphone

Apple puts events in my Calendar like "Flag Day"  Is there a way to delete such events?  When I see a "dot" on a date, and go check what it is, it's a waste of my time if it isn't an event that I've posted. Really annoying.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable unwanted calendars in Calendar.app on iPhone with these steps:

1. **open Calendar.app** in your iPhone
2. Hold your iPhone vertical
3. On the **bottom are three buttons** visible: Today, **Calendars**, Inbox if you don't see them, go back to the monthly overview)
4. Tap "**Calendars" > Hide All Calendars**
5. Now select **only the calendars you want** to see.
6. Tap "**Done**" when you're done.

Let me know if this works for you.